# How to write Regex expression for <td class="NumberCell" width="60">2</td> in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for information on how to read

```
<td class="NumberCell" width="60">2</td>
```

value 2 from this tag of html?

2 is a variable value - it can change.

How to modify this to get value present in tag?

File 1 has : 2
File 2 has : 6
File 3 has : 10

I want to extract all 3 values

Comment: It's typically less error-prone to read HTML with a dedicated HTML parsing library, such as HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Please embed the code instead of providing an image.

Comment: If you want to parse a whole HTML-File, please just read this answer (it's totaly worth reading, maybe the best answer on this site ever): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3246824

Answer (score 2):

As @John Told in comments try HTMLAgilityPack

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml("<td class=\"NumberCell\" width=\"60\">2</td>");

            foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("td"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("text=" + node.InnerText);
            }
```

Comment: regex.Match("<td class=\"NumberCell\" width=\"60\">2</td>"); 2 is a variable value - it can change. 


How to modify this to get value present in tag? 

File 1 has : <td class="NumberCell" width="60">2</td> 
File 2 has : <td class="NumberCell" width="60">6</td> 
File 3 has : <td class="NumberCell" width="60">10</td> 

I want to extract all 3 values

Answer (score 0):

You could use the expression `>(.*?)<` to do this. This pretty simple expression will give you one matching group.

Here is a simplified implementation in C#:

```
var regex = new Regex(">(.*?)<");
var match = regex.Match("<td class=\"NumberCell\" width=\"60\">2</td>");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: regex.Match("<td class=\"NumberCell\" width=\"60\">2</td>");

2 is a variable value - it can change.

How to modify this to get value present in tag?

File 1 has :  <td class="NumberCell" width="60">2</td>
File 2 has :  <td class="NumberCell" width="60">6</td>
File 3 has :  <td class="NumberCell" width="60">10</td>

I want to extract all 3 values.

Comment: @VinayKumar Question back: Do you have any knowledge in Regex? The desired behavior described by you is exactly what regex is doing for you.